# python function question with keyword args

Tags: python, function

I can not get this function to print, I am supposed to use a function with optional keyword args to make sentences.

```
I Love Chicago!
Python is great!!!!
I guess Java is okay. I guess Java is okay.
LET'S GO CUBS!!
```

here is my code which prints nothing

```
def speak(message, capitalize_message, num_times_repeat_message, num_exclamation_points=1):

    speak("I love Chicago", 1, 1, False)
    speak("Python is great", 4, 1, False)
    speak("I guess Java is okay", 0, 2, False)
    speak("LET's GO CUBS", 2, 1, True)

print(speak)
print(speak)
print(speak)
print(speak)
```

Comment: Hi @newbie-20, it's not quite clear what your code actually is! Not only should it not print what you want, it should probably give nonsensical results or even errors. You seem to have two definitions of a `speak` function, neither of which actually has any "logic" to determine what the function does -- how does it use the string and the numbers and the `True`/`False` values? Go back to the course notes, or book, and look a little more into how functions are defined and used!

Comment: 1) you're attempting to `print` a function (which I believe will output some random memory address in hex format), when what you need to do is *call* it, 2) when you do call that function your program will crash with a stack overflow because you have unlimited recursion. I suggest learning some basics about Python or prorgramming in general - particularly as regards to functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this?:

```
    def speak(message, capitals=True, num_repeats=1, num_exclame=1):
         if capitals:
             message = message.capitalize() # capitalize if needed
         message += '!' * num_exclame # add exclamation marks
         return message * num_repeats
```

then call the function like this:

```
print(speak('python is great', capitals=True, num_repeats=2, num_exclame=2))
```

or maybe have speak print it:

```
    def speak(message, capitals=True, num_repeats=1, num_exclame=1):
         if capitals:
             message = message.capitalize()
         message += '!' * num_exclame
         print(message * num_repeats)
```

and simply:

```
speak('python is great', True, 2, 3)
```

Comment: that worked!!  thank you so much !!  i had to change some numbers and boom it all worked except i needed  lets go cubs to be all caps not just first letter is there a way to do that ?  thank u again u saved me !!!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing in your function , below is the hint how you write functions:

```
def speak(message, capitalize_message, num_times_repeat_message, num_exclamation_points=1):
    print message
    #write your logic here based on parameters

#Below lines calls the speak function
speak("I love Chicago", 1, 1, False)
speak("Python is great", 4, 1, False)
speak("I guess Java is okay", 0, 2, False)
speak("LET's GO CUBS", 2, 1, True)
```

Comment: Just use the comment for the hint and please consider of not posting it as an answer.